# ImageMapster ToolTip position with the browser border

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemapster

I have a problem with the `tooltip`. When I hover on an area, a tooltip box appear on the top-left of that area. When the area is near the border of the browser, the tooltip box still appears at the same position, making some information hidden as shown below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lMfI.png)

[Here](http://quang-duy.16mb.com/demo3.htm) is my demo site (sorry somehow the javascript doesn't work on my jsfiddle).

Can anyone tell me how to make the tooltip find another place to display the whole box, for example bottom left on the above situation.